# hibernate exception while creating a table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Following a tutorial found on yt channel i tried to make a simple application using Hibernate. When I execute the code I get a bunch of exceptions and I can't indentify the reason why. However, results of creating a table and inserting data is visible and it works fine - this confuses me the most. Below I provide code for necessary classes, `persistence.xml` and stack trace. How can I solve this problem?

```
STACK TRACE:
    cze 24, 2017 7:39:31 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException
WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlString(SchemaDropperImpl.java:375)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaDropperImpl.java:359)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applyConstraintDropping(SchemaDropperImpl.java:331)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:230)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:144)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:309)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:452)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:889)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.test.Main.main(Main.java:12)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'hibernate_tests.employee' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:943)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2486)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2444)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:845)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:745)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
    ... 16 more

cze 24, 2017 7:39:31 PM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@363042d7] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
cze 24, 2017 7:39:31 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl applyImportSources
INFO: HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@59d2400d'
cze 24, 2017 7:39:31 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl stop
INFO: HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate_tests]
```

`persistence.xml`

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="myDatabase" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="miki" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="***" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate_tests" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect.storage_engine" value="innodb" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

`Main.java`

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myDatabase");
    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

    Employee employee = new Employee();
    Address address = new Address();
    employee.setAddress(address);
    employee.setFirstName("aaa");
    employee.setLastName("bbb");
    employee.setSalary(10000);

    address.setLocalization("ccc");
    address.setStreet("ddd");
    address.setPostalCode("12-456");

  /*  entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    entityManager.persist(address);
    entityManager.persist(employee);
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();*/

    entityManager.close();
    entityManagerFactory.close();
}

}
```

`Employee.java`

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;
@Column(name = "Imie")
private String firstName;
@Column(name = "Nazwisko")
private String lastName;
@Transient
private double salary;
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn
private Address address;

/*sett.&gett*/
}
```

`Address.java`

```
@Entity
public class Address {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@Column(name = "Miejscowosc")
private String localization;
@Column(name = "Ulica")
private String street;
@Column(name = "Kod_Pocztowy")
private String postalCode;
/*sett.&gett.*/
```

Comment: Try the following dialect : `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect`

Comment: Yes I tried. It works without exceptions then but MySQL uses MyISAM engine then which doesn't support foreign keys and it doesn't suit my needs.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that your database `hibernate_tests` contain the table `employee`, Second to be sure put the name of your table in the Entity like :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee", catalog = "hibernate_tests", schema = "schema_name")
public class Employee {...}
```

---

If you have a default schema then you don't need to use it just use :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {...}
```

---

If this still not work you can check using the name of your database :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee", catalog = "hibernate_tests")
public class Employee {...}
```

Comment: but isn't ` <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />` responsible for creating table if it didn't exist?

Comment: yes, but how it will created without the name of your table @MariuszMikołajczak ?

Comment: unfortunately, none of these solutions solve this problem

Comment: @MariuszMikołajczak did you get the same error or what exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find what caused the problem. Everytime before execution of java code I manually dropped down tables. When program is executed, hibernate first tries to drop the tables assuming that they exist in the database. Since I dropped them previously there was exception that table doesn't exist.
When I don't drop tables manually there is no exception.